Invoke automatic row processing (DML) process programmatically
I am using Oracle APEX 22.1.4 and I am trying to invoke automatic row processing (DML) process programmatically.
I tried as follows but it doesn't work.
apex.server.process(
    'SAVE_PERSON', // Specify your process name here
    {
       
    },
    {
        request: 'UPDATE', // Specify the DML operation (CREATE, UPDATE, DELETE, etc.)
        dataType: 'text', // Ensure the response type is handled correctly
        success: function(data) {
            console.log('DML operation executed successfully: ' + data);
        },
        error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.error('Error executing DML operation:', errorThrown);
        }
    }
);

Can anybody suggest an idea to achieve this?

afaik this is not possible in javascript. The automatic row processing is tied to a form and needs to happen in the processing section of the lifecycle of an apex page. That can only happen on page submit, not in an ajax call. Maybe this will change in later versions of apex.

First of all, to have a custom process on your page, you either need a form region or a Interactive grid:
Form - Automatic Row Processing (DML)
Process to insert, update, or delete a form region row(s).

Interactive Grid - Automatic Row Processing (DML)
Process to insert, update, or delete Interactive Grid rows.

Second point you need to consider is the Syntax:
As Help section on the page suggests:
begin
    case :APEX$ROW_STATUS
    when 'C' then
        insert into emp ( empno, ename, deptno )
        values ( :P1_EMPNO, :P1_ENAME, :P1_DEPTNO )
        returning rowid into :P1_ROWID;
    when 'U' then
        update emp
           set ename  = :P1_ENAME,
               deptno = :P1_DEPTNO
         where rowid  = :P1_ROWID;
    when 'D' then
        delete emp
         where rowid = :P1_ROWID;
    end case;
end;

You need to use this format to have a custom code as DML. The example code you are using in you question, is an example of AJAX callback Javascript function

** You of course need to modify the code and conditions for your use-case. This is just a simple example of how the PL/SQL code should be structured for custom DML.

Hi @cengiz sevimli,
Thanks for your reply. I tried this way and it wors but still I need to set 'Database Action' as 'SQL Insert Action/ SQL Update Action or SQL Delete Action' in the Behavior of the button. What I was trying is, using a single button (say 'SAV') handle both INSERT and UPDATE actions. Is there a way to handle such button action?

if it is a interactive grid, maybe you can try setting execution scope as  'all submitted rows'

Hi @cengiz, Nope, it is a form.

then in the process you are executing, check server side condition attribute "When button is pressed" and "type" "value pair".

Hi @cengiz, Yes, I tried that way. However, when click through button, I need to set either 'INSER' or 'UPDATE' action. What I need is, handle both actions using a single button. For ex, if :P3_PK_ITEM_ID is null then => call Automatic Row Processing (DML) with INSERT DB action otherwise call Automatic Row Processing (DML) with UPDATE DB action when clicking on 'SAVE' button. Your above code only works when calling through two separate buttons.
